# "Subquery returns more than 1 row" in SQL (From Leetcode 178. Rank Scores)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am solving the SQL problem from [Leetcode: 178. Rank Scores.](https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/description/).

The question of the leetcode is this:

Write an SQL query to **rank the scores**. The ranking should be calculated according to the following rules:

- The scores should be ranked from the highest to the lowest.
- If there is a tie between two scores, both should have the same
  ranking.
- After a tie, the next ranking number should be the next consecutive
  integer value. In other words, there should be no holes between
  ranks.

Return the result table ordered by score in descending order.
The query result format is in the following example.

Input:

```
Scores table:
+----+-------+
| id | score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+
```

Output:

```
+-------+------+
| score | rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 3.85  | 2    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.50  | 4    |
+-------+------+
```

Note: id is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table contains the score of a game. Score is a floating point value with two decimal places.

I tried the below solution:

```
SELECT  s2.score,  
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s2.score) 
             FROM Scores s1                 
             WHERE s1.score >= s2.score) 'rank'
FROM Scores s2
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Then it prompts an error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. However when I changed `DISTINCT s2.score` to `DISTINCT s1.score`, then it works and the solution is accepted.

I had been search this question for a long time and I did not get an answer to solve my doubt in this context. I wonder

- how which syntax cause it `returns more than 1 row`?
- Why change `DISTINCT s2.score` to `DISTINCT s1.score` solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 'You can refer more detail via this link.  -' or you could include everything of use in the question..

Comment: Your query shouldn't raise that error. Note that you count different things when you switch between s1.score and s2.score.

Comment: @jarlh my query does raise that error.

Comment: That's very strange, must be a bug.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT s2.score)` will always return 1. `COUNT(DISTINCT s1.score)` will return something else (depending on table data.)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to help improve your question

Comment: Your query makes no logical sense and a different error can be produced see https://dbfiddle.uk/POI67V59 what version of mysql are you on? nb I can reproduce your error in mariadb which says something (not sure what though)

Comment: as a side note, the query you are showing has nothing to do with solving the problem which is about ranking not counting.  you should look at the documentation for dense_rank()

Comment: `DISTINCT s2.score` this is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` https://dbfiddle.uk/N6ff2-Zh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a "correlated subquery" you should **only** refer to the "outer table" (s2) in the `where clause` of that subquery. You cannot ALSO refer to s2 in the select clause of the subquery because s2 isn't part of the `from clause` of that subquery.

Imagine that you wrote this query:

```
select s2.x from table1 as s1
```

That will fail because s2 is not part of the from clause of that query. However it gets more complex, and confusing, in the your subquery because although s2 is a valid alias it will not work (as you expect) in the select clause of the subquery.

Also: The error message you are getting occurs in MySQL 5.6 (and possibly other versions) but you would get a different message in MySQL regarding only_full_group_by. In my view neither error message really describes the actual error (that you have referenced the outer table in the select clause of a correlated subquery).

When you do refer to s1 in the select clause of the subquery you now are referring to the data available via the subquery's `from clause`, and hence it will run successfully. i.e.

```
SELECT  s2.score,  
            (SELECT COUNT(distinct s1.score) 
             FROM Scores as s1                 
             WHERE s1.score >= s2.score) 'rank'
FROM `Scores` s2
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Produces:

```
score   rank
4.00    1
4.00    1
3.85    2
3.65    3
3.65    3
3.50    4
```

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/M1tUPqDD

Hopefully this explains why you got the error, and why it works when you select from s1 instead of s2.

---

Think of this portion being the core subquery:

```
             SELECT COUNT(distinct s1.score) 
             FROM Scores as s1
```

and then think of this portion as being how the "correlation" is created:

```
             WHERE s1.score >= s2.score
```

Only refer to any "outer tables" in that second portion.

Answer (score 0):

My result..

`select score,dense_rank() over (order by score desc ) r_rank from ranks`

https://dbfiddle.uk/Bp2w7WZ6